# Does importing Android "package" import resources?

Tags: java, android, gradle, dependencies

I'm trying to use the following library:

https://github.com/AppSci/SleepTimePicker

I'm able to import it by adding it to my `build.gradle` - `dependencies`. Then on my `layout` I'm able to find this `picker` after my gradle syncs: `<com.appsci.sleep.timepicker.SleepTimePicker />`

However I'm wondering whats the best way to proceed using those external "libraries", can I access their drawables / layouts and other resources that are inside the github repository, or I have to download them manually and create them if I want to use them and this "include" only imports the java / kotlin code there is ?

Comment: That should be included in your case...

Comment: How can I access them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's an android library (aar) it does contain them and you are free to use them. Don't load them more times or your apk will be bigger if it has duplicated resources.

More info here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library

> Unlike JAR files, AAR files can contain Android resources and a manifest file, which allows you to bundle in shared resources like layouts and drawables in addition to Java classes and methods.

But you can also use java libs (jar) in your dependencies and if you need android resources with them you'll have to manually add them to your project.

If you want to use a drawable of a lib you need to add an uri in the layout root element for that lib:

```
xmlns:timepicker="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.appsci.sleep.sleeptimepicker"
```

And then access the drawable using it:

```
@timepicker:drawable/ic_bed_time_dark
```

Answer (score 0):

No! if you want to import dependency of the library that you noticed, you can't use its resources like images and etc. If you want to use them, you should download and put them manually in your resource.
Happy Coding ;)